# Switch audio output between audio output, headphones, iPhone earpiece and speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, audio, bluetooth

I am trying to give the a user the ability to switch audio output in my application and I am able to go to between speaker and back using AVAudioSession but I can not find a way to go between a connected bluetooth device and the headphones, in any order.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: They do it on the iPhone call screen.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can set the `overrideOutputAudioPort` to one of the following.

```
/* output port types */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortLineOut          NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Line level output on a dock connector */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones       NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Headphone or headset output */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP    NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Output on a Bluetooth A2DP device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* The speaker you hold to your ear when on a phone call */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker   NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Built-in speaker on an iOS device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortHDMI             NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Output via High-Definition Multimedia Interface */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay          NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Output on a remote Air Play device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothLE      NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); /* Output on a Bluetooth Low Energy device */
```

Comment: `overrideOutputAudioPort` takes a `UInt` as parameter, you gave a list of `NSString`.